# Prolog: Stating more facts in less statements

Tags: prolog

I have a problem in Prolog and I really really need help with it.

There are people (male and female) and they have propterties:

- Name
- Gender
- Age
- Weight
- Hair color
  and
- favourite song
- favourite sport
- favourite book

I need state these facts about a person, but I am not supposed to state more than 3 facts! 
could someone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an easy way:

```
person(PersonName, Gender, Age, Weight, HairColor).
favorite(PersonName, Song, Sport, Book).
```

There's no reason you have to limit yourself to arity-1 or -2 facts. You can design your Prolog fact database the same way you would design a relational database. Prolog will index the first term of the fact automatically anyway, so make that a candidate key and observe as your program performs well despite the apparent searching. :)

**Edit**: To illustrate a few queries:

```
person(maria, female, 28, 61, blond).
```

Is there a person named Maria?

```
?- person(maria, _, _, _, _).
yes.
```

What is Maria's favorite sport?

```
?- favorite(maria, _, Sport, _).
Sport = tennis ;
no.
```

etc. For more details, see @mbratch's comment below.

Comment: am I supposed to add []?
I mean: 
person(maria, [female, 28, 61, blond]).

Comment: @Marci-man Absolutely not. `person(maria, female, 28, 61, blond).`

Comment: but then I can't seem to ask a question: person(maria). 
i get an error: uncaught exception: error(existence_error(procedure,person/1),top_level/0)

Comment: @Marci-man Well, that's because we defined `person/5`, not `person/1`. If this was a requirement you shouldn't have left it out of your question. The query obviously would work with `person(maria, _, _, _, _).` You could rename this one `about_person(marie, female, 28, 61, blond).` and then define `person(X) :- about_person(X, _, _, _, _)` if you really must.

Comment: great, thanks. but I have another questions, how do I go about asking questions, like does maria like tennis?

Comment: @Marci-man, if you used your previous suggestion of `person(maria, [female, 28, 61, blond]).` then your query `person(maria)` would fail in that case as well. Using the data representation that Daniel's showing, you can devise any query scheme you wish with predicates, per his commented example.

Comment: @Marci-man, you can query: `favorite(maria, _, tennis, _).`, or you can create a predicate such as, `likes_sport(Person, Sport) :- favorite(Person, _, Sport, _).` then query, `likes_sport(maria, tennis).` Or if you want to find out what sport(s) maria likes, you'd query, `likes_sport(maria, Sport).`.

Comment: @DanielLyons read your "Why ORM Divides Us" and really enjoyed it, too bad there is no way of leaving comments on the blog... thought I'd leave on here!

Comment: Thanks. I'd prefer email. I don't have comments because it just leads to trash talk in our profession.